# Several MongoDB nodes in a single Datasource

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, sharding, jasperserver, mongodb-java

I need to apply a whole IP range as a Datasource for the reports,
because for the big data, we have a big cluster (several mongo servers/shards/nodes).

If one fails, it should use the next node.

Is this possible within JasperServer/Reports ?

If you're not sure what I mean, I'm talking about the datasource resource descriptor:

```
<resourceDescriptor name="..." wsType="datasource" uriString="..." isNew="true">
```

or for the ones only using the GUI:[image]

Comment: Probably belongs on serverfault.com. Or should be post at http://community.jaspersoft.com

Comment: You don't get answers on jaspersoft.com. This is not a server question. I ask for a Java-based software issue.

Comment: Don't you have a master node to point it to?

Comment: @johansson.lc unfortunately not. we are able to set an IP pool to use in other software (to use the next if first fails), but not within Jasper